# How to debug StoreOnce Oracle RMAN plugin on HP-UX?

Tags: hp-ux, oracle-database

We have an old Oracle 10g database on old Itanium machine (BL870c i2) which is running HP-UX B.11.31 (it appears to be latest version). Also we have a StoreOnce 3640 (s/w version 4.2.1-1942.21, which means it's gen4).

The natural way to backup the database is to use supplied Catalyst RMAN plugin. We successfully use this plugin of version 3.4.0 on the neighbor Oracle Linux machine with Oracle Database 11g R2.

The installation of the plugin on HP-UX went successfully. However, when running a backup, it doesn't work, logging the following error message:

```
2022-09-29 09:22:19.456266 (local 13:22) : ERROR : 12217_1 : 3 : TC :  16 : 192.168.221.150 : Ix : OSCPP : osCltCrypt_HashPasswordStringSecureMode : Ln 202 : Failed to hash the password (Secure Mode). callStatus : 0
2022-09-29 09:22:19.464390 (local 13:22) : ERROR : 12217_1 : 3 : TC :  16 : 192.168.221.150 : Ix : OSCPP : osCltCrypt_HashPasswordStringSecureMode : Ln 204 : GOTO ReturnStatus = -1000 (OSCLT_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR).
2022-09-29 09:22:19.464655 (local 13:22) : ERROR : 12217_1 : 3 : TC :  16 : 192.168.221.150 : Ix : OSCPP : osCltTrnCmd_OpenCommandSession : Ln 394 : Failed to create a Secure Mode hashed password.
2022-09-29 09:22:19.464701 (local 13:22) : ERROR : 12217_1 : 3 : TC :  16 : 192.168.221.150 : Ix : OSCPP : osCltTrnCmd_OpenCommandSession : Ln 395 : GOTO ReturnStatus = -1000 (OSCLT_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR).
2022-09-29 09:22:19.464768 (local 13:22) : ERROR : 12217_1 : 3 : TMC : OSCPP : osCltTeamCmd_OpenCommandSession : Ln 472 : Failed to open initial cmd transport, error -1000.
2022-09-29 09:22:19.464815 (local 13:22) : ERROR : 12217_1 : 3 : TMC : OSCPP : osCltTeamCmd_OpenCommandSession : Ln 478 : GOTO ReturnStatus = -1000 (OSCLT_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR).
2022-09-29 09:22:19.464904 (local 13:22) : ERROR : 12217_1 : 3 : C : OSCPP : osCltCmd_OpenCommandSessionInternal : Ln 306 : Unable to open command session to server : 192.168.221.150 (port : 9387). Error: -1000.
2022-09-29 09:22:19.464955 (local 13:22) : ERROR : 12217_1 : 3 : C : OSCPP : osCltCmd_OpenCommandSessionInternal : Ln 307 : GOTO ReturnStatus = -1000 (OSCLT_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR).
2022-09-29 09:22:19.470774 (local 13:22) : ERROR : 12217_1 : 0 : +C : OSCPP : Open : Ln 188 : EXCEPTION: Open command session to 192.168.221.150 failed. retryCount 0. : OSCLT_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR [-1000] (from:Open@188)
2022-09-29 09:22:20.062702 (local 13:22) : ERROR : 12217_1 : 6 : TC :  16 : 192.168.221.150 : Ix : OSCPP : osCltCrypt_HashPasswordStringSecureMode : Ln 202 : Failed to hash the password (Secure Mode). callStatus : 0
2022-09-29 09:22:20.062808 (local 13:22) : ERROR : 12217_1 : 6 : TC :  16 : 192.168.221.150 : Ix : OSCPP : osCltCrypt_HashPasswordStringSecureMode : Ln 204 : GOTO ReturnStatus = -1000 (OSCLT_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR).
2022-09-29 09:22:20.062942 (local 13:22) : ERROR : 12217_1 : 6 : TC :  16 : 192.168.221.150 : Ix : OSCPP : osCltTrnCmd_OpenCommandSession : Ln 394 : Failed to create a Secure Mode hashed password.
2022-09-29 09:22:20.062989 (local 13:22) : ERROR : 12217_1 : 6 : TC :  16 : 192.168.221.150 : Ix : OSCPP : osCltTrnCmd_OpenCommandSession : Ln 395 : GOTO ReturnStatus = -1000 (OSCLT_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR).
2022-09-29 09:22:20.063063 (local 13:22) : ERROR : 12217_1 : 6 : TMC : OSCPP : osCltTeamCmd_OpenCommandSession : Ln 472 : Failed to open initial cmd transport, error -1000.
2022-09-29 09:22:20.063110 (local 13:22) : ERROR : 12217_1 : 6 : TMC : OSCPP : osCltTeamCmd_OpenCommandSession : Ln 478 : GOTO ReturnStatus = -1000 (OSCLT_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR).
2022-09-29 09:22:20.063159 (local 13:22) : ERROR : 12217_1 : 6 : C : OSCPP : osCltCmd_OpenCommandSessionInternal : Ln 306 : Unable to open command session to server : 192.168.221.150 (port : 9387). Error: -1000.
2022-09-29 09:22:20.063262 (local 13:22) : ERROR : 12217_1 : 6 : C : OSCPP : osCltCmd_OpenCommandSessionInternal : Ln 307 : GOTO ReturnStatus = -1000 (OSCLT_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR).
2022-09-29 09:22:20.063342 (local 13:22) : ERROR : 12217_1 : 0 : +C : OSCPP : Open : Ln 188 : EXCEPTION: Open command session to 192.168.221.150 failed. retryCount 0. : OSCLT_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR [-1000] (from:Open@188)
```

(`192.168.221.150` is the StoreOnce IP address). From the first line I could infer that there's some function `osCltCrypt_HashPasswordStringSecureMode` which is supposed to create some hash of the password and fails.

How to find out what went wrong and why it doesn't work? And, to fix, supposedly?

**UPD:** if we make the Catalyst datastore public (ouch) and remove (comment out) the client name and password in the `plugin.conf` on the client, backup works. It looks like some library is missing in our HP-UX installation that is required to hash the password, and if the passwordless mode is configured, this step is ommited and everything else works.

**UPD:** tried to run `ldd libisvsupport_rman.so` (which is 38 MB plugin binary). The result is:

```
libisvsupport_rman.so:
        libdl.so.1 =>   /usr/lib/hpux64/libdl.so.1
        libstd_v2.so.1 =>       /usr/lib/hpux64/libstd_v2.so.1
        libCsup.so.1 => /usr/lib/hpux64/libCsup.so.1
        libm.so.1 =>    /usr/lib/hpux64/libm.so.1
        libunwind.so.1 =>       /usr/lib/hpux64/libunwind.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>    /usr/lib/hpux64/libc.so.1
        libuca.so.1 =>  /usr/lib/hpux64/libuca.so.1
        libpthread.so.1 =>      /usr/lib/hpux64/libpthread.so.1
```

**UPD:** Tried to install the OpenSSL library from `OpenSSL_A.01.01.01p.001_HP-UX_B.11.31_IA_PA.depot`, as suggested in the answer. That didn't help, nothing changed at all.

Answer (score 0):

As a wild guess, the library needed for creating the password hash just might be OpenSSL.

The default version of OpenSSL that comes with HP-UX might be quite old, and not support the hash algorithm the plugin is trying to use.

However, HP Enterprise provides newer versions of OpenSSL for HP-UX for free, here: https://myenterpriselicense.hpe.com/cwp-ui/software

Type "openssl" into the "Enter your Search Term(s)..." field, and click on Search. Pick the one whose Overview says "HP-UX OpenSSL". The other versions available seem to be for HP NonStop-OSS, i.e. what used to be Tandem: a very different OS.

Comment: thank you, we'll try that. However, I tried to run `ldd libisvsupport_rman.so` and it doesn't seem to depend on libssl or libcrypto.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not helped :(

Comment: As I said, it was a wild guess. You’ll probably need to contact the support of the RMAN backup plugin, unless someone who has had the exact same issue reads the question and writes an answer.